# Does the Battle Aspect utility power trigger the Cloak of Translocation's property?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

The Battle Aspect utility power reads as follows (PHB3 pag 50):

> Battle Aspect Battlemind Utility 10
>
> Daily ✦ Polymorph, Psionic, Teleportation
>
> Minor Action Personal
>
> Effect: Until the end of the encounter, you gain resist 5 to all damage and can teleport 3 squares as a move action.

The Cloak of Translocation (AV2 pag 66) reads as follows:

> Cloak of Translocation Level 9+
>
> Item Slot: Neck
>
> Enhancement: Fortitude, Reflex, and Will
>
> Property: When you use a teleportation power, you gain a +2 bonus to AC and Reflex until the end of your next turn.
>
> Power (Daily): Minor Action. You regain the use of an encounter teleportation power that you have already used during this encounter.

My question is twofold:

- Does activating battle aspect trigger the cloak's property? My guess is yes, since I am using a teleportation power (the keyword is there).
- Does using a move action to teleport 3 squares trigger the cloak's property? My guess would be no, because I already "used" the teleportation power, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I updated fhe formatting for your question. Let me know if I broke anything :) Welcome to the site!

Comment: All good thanks :D couldn't figure out how to get it done on mobile...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cloak's property when you first use **Battle Aspect** since it is a teleportation power by virtue of having the Teleportation keyword. Using the effect is not “using” the power. You're just engaging a convenient effect you acquired.

> *Whatever is described in an “Effect” entry simply happens*, regardless of its position in the sequence of entries. (Rules Compendium page 96, emphasis mine)